# Запрещение обработки одиночных % в sprintf

Tags: php

Функция sprintf считывает для замены все символы, содержащие знак процента, но как быть если в строке нужны проценты? То есть, вот такая конструкция выдает ошибку:

```
$str = '%s имеет 50% акций';
sprintf($str, 'Вася');
```

как это обойти?

Comment: Правильный ответ дал Яков. Для задания знака процента в `printf` используется конструкция `%%`. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '%s имеет 50\% акций';
sprintf($str, 'Вася');
```

Comment: не запрещение, а экранирование

Comment: а вообще пользуйтесь функцией    `echo`

Comment: спасибо, но меня волнует еще обработка данных, например, если пользователь отсылает сообщение и в нем необходимо обработать % таким образом, то как быть? str_replace?

Comment: Вам же сказали использовать echo. Если же вы хотите следовать своему методу, то придется проверять: переменная ли подставляется, или же это просто проценты. preg_replace скорее всего.

Answer (score 0):

Для экранирования символа `%` в строке формата используется удвоение: `%%`

```
$str = '%s имеет 50%% акций';
sprintf($str, 'Вася');
```

Comment: Напиште строчку в ответ, что нужно %% использовать.